# R: Rename duplicate variables by replicating and extending other variable names from a consistent relative position

Tags: r, rename, tibble

Starting at the 14th column, I have duplicate `Z` variables every 4 columns (about 25 times):

```
... Apple  X  Y **Z** Car  X  Y **Z** Hike  X  Y **Z** Door  X  Y **Z**...
... 14     25 64  26  14   37 35  13  35    75 23  12  58    32 72  36 ...
... 35     14 75  23  14   64 87  64  42    21 35  75  34    24 63  34 ...
```

(Here, `Apple` is the 11th column)

I plan on removing the `X` and `Y` variables (with `df[!duplicated(colnames(df)]`), but to do that (and to be able to use the `Z` variables), my understanding is that the `Z` variables must not be duplicates.

I want to rename `Z` variables so that they take names from the variable 3 columns behind, followed by '_RT'. So for example, the first `Z` in that table would become `Apple_RT`, the second `Z` would become `Car_RT`, and so on.

Once Z variables have been renamed and X and Y variables removed, the data should look like this (plus the unchanged preceding 10 variables):

```
... Apple  Apple_RT Car  Car_RT Hike  Hike_RT Door  Door_RT ...
... 14     26       14   13     35    12      58    36      ...
... 35     23       14   64     42    75      34    34      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data** *I changed the sample data a bit, but follows the same principle. Start here would be at 3, which is the first "category" Apple*

```
df <- structure(list(A = 1, B = 2, APPLE = 3, X = 4, Y = 5, Z = 6, CAR = 7, X = 8, Y = 9, Z = 10, HIKE = 7, X = 8, Y = 9, Z = 10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))

#   A B APPLE X Y Z CAR X Y  Z HIKE X Y  Z
# 1 1 2     3 4 5 6   7 8 9 10    7 8 9 10
```

**solution**

```
start = 3

v <- names(df)
keep <- v[1:(start-1)]
cats <- v[start:length(v)]
cats <- cats[!cats %in% cats[duplicated(cats)]]


out <- df[!names(df) %in% c("X", "Y")]
names(out) <- c(keep, unlist(lapply(cats, function(x) c(x, paste0(x, "_RT")))))
```

**output**

```
out

#   A B APPLE APPLE_RT CAR CAR_RT HIKE HIKE_RT
# 1 1 2     3        6   7     10    7      10
```